# Mesh problems in texture painting

Tags: mesh, texture-painting

[image]im having an issue when texture painting my mesh, as you can see that areas have a diferent tone and shape, whenever i try to paint something, even a little thing fills all that area. Before texture painting i joined different meshes to create that "head" like ears and neck, i don't know if thats what caused that

Comment: I'm just spitballing, but what does it look like in shading mode? It looks like you've turned off visibility for all meshes but the one you have in the screenshot. Is that correct?

Comment: It looks like this, other meshes don't have a texture https://imgur.com/a/J4kHaDq

Comment: I ask because I'm trying to isolate the mesh you're trying to fix. You could have multiple meshes with multiple textures/no textures. You didn't rename your meshes in your collection, so it's hard to tell what's what. The only visible mesh I can see is called "cube," which lacks useful information. Does that mesh include both the face and head, or are the face and head separate? My first thought is that you have two different head meshes overlapping. That's why I need to know if you've turned of visibility for all the meshes but one.

Comment: Oh! my bad im sorry https://imgur.com/a/FcqeJmH looking at my wireframe it looks kinda weird in those areas, like empty, it's my first day sculpting and my second day using blender so i really don't know much about what happened there :(

Comment: Is the mesh properly UV unwrapped? Texture painting works with the UV mapping of an object so it is important to get this right.

Comment: That's cool. I had a lot of problems accidentally deleting faces, screwing up normals, etc when I first started out, so I understand. I'd recommend dividing your project into smaller pieces at first. Make the head, face, eyes, ears, hair, clothing, etc separate objects. Use a UV grid to make sure you have good seams and try a test layer of paint before you join objects together for the final texturing work. Also, be organized. Name all your objects, materials, textures, etc. appropriately. It will help you and help others help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! will do, i had a problem w my uv unwrapping but it's all fixed now, i was so frustrated. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Hi Eric! yeah its was a problem with my uv unwrap, but its all fixed now thank you!